# Flask create_app will not initializing db instance extension in init

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, psycopg2

In the below two code snippets, the first one works fine where I create a connection object that gets imported thoughout the app but its not in the create_app() method. its global. However when I create a DB class and try to follow steps to instantiate in create_app(). it doesnt work, any help is appreciated.
**This works perfectly fine**

```
import os
from flask import Flask, current_app
import psycopg2
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_script import Manager
from flask_mail import Mail
from Flask_blog.database_queries import *
from Flask_blog.config import Config

connection = psycopg2.connect("postgres://postgres:postgres...url")
bcrypt = Bcrypt()
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.login_view = 'users.login'
login_manager.login_message_category = 'info'
mail = Mail()

#to run scripts or functions at start-up
script_manager = Manager()
script_manager.add_command('setup_database', Initial_checks(connection))


def create_app(config_class=Config):

    app = Flask(__name__) #app variable being set an Instance of Flask class
    app.config.from_object(Config)

    bcrypt.init_app(app)
    login_manager.init_app(app)
    mail.init_app(app)
    script_manager(app)

    from Flask_blog.users.routes import users
    from Flask_blog.posts.routes import posts
    from Flask_blog.main.routes import main

    app.register_blueprint(users)
    app.register_blueprint(posts)
    app.register_blueprint(main)
    return app
```

When I try to create a psycopg2 DB class and create an extension as with other plugins, it doesnt work with any error. **This doesnt Work**

```
import os
from flask import Flask, current_app
import psycopg2
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_script import Manager
from flask_mail import Mail
from Flask_blog.database_queries import *
from Flask_blog.config import Config
    
#CREATING THIS CLASS FOR DB
class PostgresConnection(object):
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.connection = None

    def init_app(self, app):
            #self.connection = psycopg2.connect(app.config['POSTGRES_URL'])
            self.connection = psycopg2.connect("postgres://postgres:....url")

bcrypt = Bcrypt()
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.login_view = 'users.login'
login_manager.login_message_category = 'info'
mail = Mail()
connection = PostgresConnection() # CREATING EXTENSION

#to run scripts or functions at start-up
script_manager = Manager()
script_manager.add_command('setup_database', Initial_checks(connection))


def create_app(config_class=Config):

    app = Flask(__name__) #app variable being set an Instance of Flask class
    app.config.from_object(Config)

    #connectioned = psycopg2.connect(app.config['POSTGRES_URL'])
    #connection = connectioned

    bcrypt.init_app(app)
    login_manager.init_app(app)
    mail.init_app(app)
    script_manager(app)
    connection.init_app(app) #####


    from Flask_blog.users.routes import users
    from Flask_blog.posts.routes import posts
    from Flask_blog.main.routes import main

    app.register_blueprint(users)
    app.register_blueprint(posts)
    app.register_blueprint(main)
    return app
```

Only error I get is this and I am unable to understand. The below code i've used without issues before

```
  File "d:\project7\Flask_blog\database_queries.py", line 6, in Run_Query
    with connection:
AttributeError: __enter__
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your snippets don't show where `Initial_checks` comes from.

Looks like it is trying to use `connection` as a context manager.

In the first case it works because it is passed the return value of `psycopg2.connect`.

In the second case (init_app) it doesn't work because

- you're passing it a `PostgresConnection` instance, not the `connection` attribute
- the `connection` attribute is not set at import time anyway

The problem lies in the fact that you're calling `Initial_checks` at import time while your connection can only be ready at app init time.

Those checks should be postponed to init time.

Comment: you are right, the script manager was causing the crash, i removed that for now. I was not needed, I can add initial checks in the register route. Thank you